# No signal on external monitors via USB-C to DisplayPort to DVI

Tags: display, usb, displayport, dvi

For the past few months I've been plugging into two monitors (HP 1920x1080) via the following connection without issue:
MacBook **|** [USB-C -> DisplayPort (adapter)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08MQDPF28) **|** DisplayPort (cable) **|** Monitor

I recently had to move to a different building at my company that has older monitors (<s>Lenovo</s> Acer 1680x1050) which only have VGA and DVI ports. <s>This is the the new connection that i'm using:</s> One of them is using:
MacBook **|** [USB-C -> DisplayPort (adapter)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08MQDPF28) **|** [DisplayPort -> DVI (adapter)](https://www.startech.com/en-us/audio-video-products/dp2dvi) **|** DVI (cable) **|** [Monitor](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/professional-model/UM.EV6AA.002)
And the other is using:
MacBook **|** [USB-C -> DisplayPort (adapter)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08MQDPF28) **|** [DisplayPort -> DVI (cable)](https://www.startech.com/en-us/audio-video-products/dp2dvi2mm6) **|** [Monitor](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/professional-model/UM.EV6AA.002)

When connected to the <s>Lenovos</s> Acers I get "no signal" and my MacBook does not detect them. I've also confirmed that I can still use the HPs just fine. Something else to mention is that **each monitor is using its own USB-C port** so I'm not using any kind of splitter/hub/etc. It seems like my issue points to either the older <s>Lenovos</s> Acers **or** the DVI connection being incompatible with newer USB-C version (3.1?).

Has anyone else had similar issues? Can anyone confirm if one of my guesses might be correct? Thank you for any help and/or insight in advance.

macOS Monterey
Version: 12.5 (21G72)
MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019)
Processor: 2.6 GHz 6-Core Intel Core i7
Memory: 32 GB 2667 MHz DDR4
Graphics: AMD Radeon Pro 5300M 4 GB

[image: Full connection layout]

[image: USB-C to DisplayPort (adapter)]

[image: DisplayPort to DVI (adapter)]

[image: DVI (cable)]

[image: DisplayPort to DVI (cable)]

Comment: Some adapters only work "one way", for example, DVI to DisplayPort, but not the other way round. Could you share the make and model of both adapters?

Comment: Hey @jaume - Thanks for the reply. I've run into the "one-way" cables before so I think you make a good point. However, I believe that everything is set up with the correct flow direction. I updated the post with some links to the adapters to see if that helps.  
Another thing I realized is that one of the monitors is hooked up exactly like the HP ones that actually do work. This strengthens my belief that it may be that the Acer monitors are just old and might not work with the conversion that's trying to take place.